# stripe/stripe-react-native installed but got error

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I installed stripe with yarn add @stripe/stripe-react-native, than I want to run npx pod-install  but facing this error , how can I solve it?

I tried deleting podfile.lock , node modules, than installed it with yarn but got same error

Comment: I think you forgot to paste the error 

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.